# Mostrar de manera correcta la imagen completa

Tags: html, css

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590507014612-08b6a0b4e31e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1568&q=80"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```

La idea es poder mostrar la imagen completa, sin que esta se corte.

Intente darle los siguientes estilos:

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

Pero no obtengo los resultados que deseo.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto para que se muestre completamente la imagen?

Les dejo un ejemplo para que puedan ver el resultado que obtengo:

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      img {
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590507014612-08b6a0b4e31e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1568&q=80"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que se ajuste la imagen puedes agregar el stilo al img:

```
width: 100%;  min-height: 100px; max-height: 100%;
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      img {
        width: 100%;
        --object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;  min-height: 100px; max-height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590507014612-08b6a0b4e31e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1568&q=80"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Lo habia intentado antes, pero la imagen se distorciona.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simple de que la imagen se escale y que no sobre pase los limites de su contenedor es:

- La ponemos como fondo del mismo usando `background-image: url(...)`.
- Evitamos que la misma se repita aplicando `background-repeat: no-repeat`.
- Especificamos que el tamaño este contenido con `background-size: contain`.
- **Opcional**: si la queremos centrar usamos `background-position: center`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
.h1 {
  height: 100px;
}
.h2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container h1" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/wyfv15M/photo-1590507014612-08b6a0b4e31e.jpg')"></div>

<div class="container h2" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/wyfv15M/photo-1590507014612-08b6a0b4e31e.jpg')"></div>
```